# Scikit-learn DictVectorizer to Classifier

Tags: python, vector, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to load a dictionary, and then perform classification. However, I get the error:

```
  File "train_classifier.py", line 49, in <module>
    clf.fit(page_vecs.data[:-1],page_vecs.target[:-1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 505, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: target not found
```

How can I load the targets? Here is my code:

```
vec = DictVectorizer()
page_vecs = vec.fit_transform(feature_dict_list)
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)
clf.fit(page_vecs.data[:-1],page_vecs.target[:-1])
print(clf.predict(page_vecs[-1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.fit_transform) class, specifically its fit_transform method:

> Returns:
>   Xa : {array, sparse matrix}
>
> Feature vectors; always 2-d.

So it returns a 2d array.

In your code, this line:

> page_vecs = vec.fit_transform(feature_dict_list)

Will cause `page_vecs` to be such a 2d array. 2d numpy arrays have no `target` attribute, which you try to use here:

> clf.fit(page_vecs.data[:-1],page_vecs.target[:-1])

That is why you get the error. In fact, you shouldn't even do `.data`, you should work with the numpy array directly. If you want to ignore the last row, do:

```
page_vecs[:-1, :]
```

Your labels (or targets) have nothing to do with the `DictVectorizer` class, which only vectorizes your samples, not your labels. You should have a separate vector for the labels.

Comment: Ohh, I see. I guess the confusion came from the sample datasets in the sklearn tutorial. Those samples all had `targets`, but now I see that's not part of any other sklearn object.